# Silverstripe | Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, hosting, silverstripe

Silverstripe is running on my since a few weeks. Recently, I get an Internal Server Error message when I try to access the admin area.

Having a look in the server's error logs, I discovered following hint:

> [Mon Apr 05 12:15:26 2010] [error]
>   [client ...] Premature end of script
>   headers: main.php

I already was refered to this site: [What does the 'premature end of script headers' error mean?](http://bit.ly/9Ff5Tl)

But does anybody had this problem in connection with Silverstripe? Would make it much easier to restrict the scope from where the error is caused.

Regards, 
Benedikt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it seems to work now.

**Reason:**
SilverStripe required a seperate 'Security.ss'-template for the login area. *(I wonder, why it didn't was in need of that, before!)*

Unfortunatelly the web server displayed a very general 'Internal Server Error'-Message. When **i ran the site on another server**, SilverStripe was able to display error messages to me.

Answer (score 0):

insert

```
Director::set_environment_type("dev");
```

in your _config.php to see more error messages.

dont use this in live mode, only dev mode.